AC Condensate Drain Line - drain connection cleanout
See picture below for my AC drain line. When I bought the house the condensate drain line wasn't aligned with the in ground drain so I put that blue tubing on it to ensure all the condensation made it in to the drain. I believe this underground line connects to my sewer line and the sewer cleanouts are about 2 feet away from this in-ground drain. As you can see from the picture the drain is now full of of water so it needs to be cleaned out somehow. Any advice on how to clean this out? I assume it has a P-trap or check valve or something connecting to the sewer line that is clogged. I don't know how to tackle this so any advice would be appreciated.
https://i.imgur.com/UZJR2JO.jpg

Ok thanks, any thoughts on how I attempt to clean out this drain line?

This can be location dependant.  In south west Fla. most all the local building departments do not allow AC drains to be tied into waste drains.  The code requires them to be terminated outside the home a minimum of 8 inches from the structure.
You should consider having the drain run out onto the ground, unless your local demands something else.  With the drain running on the ground, it is easier to clean out. The pipe coming out of the ground is then unimportant and can be capped.
The method used here most often is to blow out the line. A shop vac reversed to blow, or a pump sprayer is used with a bulb adapter to provide a seal.
Sometimes blowing in one end of a drain is coupled with suction on the outside to free a stubborn clog.  Then it is recommended to add a little (1/4) cup of bleach every 2 to 6 months, to the line to help keep it clear.  But this option is unavailable to you.
